# Referencing hosting assembly in (Iron)Python script fails

Tags: c#, ironpython

I’m currently testing IronPython (I know a bit C# and a bit CPython). Now I want to use my custom class in a Python script.

I have the following project structure:

```
Solution IPTest
---Project IPTest
------Namespace IPTest
---------Program class (main)
---------Elem class
------Scripts
---------Worker.py
```

Where Elem is a simple:

```
public class Elem {
    public string Name;
}
```

I can use the Python scripts in the .NET program without any problems like:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("./Scripts/Worker.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
// or var worker = Python.CreateRuntime().UseFile("./Scripts/Worker.py");
dynamic Worker = scope.GetVariable("Worker");
dynamic worker = Worker();
var res1 = worker.add(4, 5);
```

However, I can’t figure out how to reference the hosting Assembly in the Python script. After some research I tried the following:

```
import sys
import System
sys.path.append(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) #make sure assembly dir is  in sys.path
import clr
clr.AddReference(“IPTest.exe”)
# or clr.AddReferenceToFile(r"IPTest.exe")
# or clr.AddReference(r"<fullpath>\IPTest\bin\Debug\IPTest.exe")
# or clr.AddReference(“../IPTest.exe”) #when not adding workingdir to sys.path
from IPTest import Elem
# or from IPTest.IPTest import Elem
# or import Elem
```

Neither works. I get two different error messages:

1. When adding workingdir to sys.path or using relative path or use
   AddReferenceToFile: No module named IPTest
2. When using the absolute path: The given assembly name or codebase
   was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I checked that the Assembly name is really IPTest and tried to use a dll instead of exe - though it should usually not make any difference and surprisingly doesn’t work either.

**disclaimer**: The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394679/embedding-ironpython-cant-add-reference-to-system):

```
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); //in c#
from IPTest import Elem # in python script
```

works just fine. However I think it should also work by referencing in the script file (which would be nicer).

Probably I’m missing something obvious, but I just can’t see it so any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `clr.AddReferenceToFile(r'IPTest.exe')` as mentioned in your error:

1. When adding workingdir to sys.path or using relative path or use **AddReferenceToFile:** No module named IPTest

Comment: I'm going crazy... I tried `clr.AddReferenceToFile(r"IPTest.exe")` (with " than ') - that doesn't work. However when using ' everything is running smooth. Thanks anyway.